# Test destination view controller when split controller detail view points to a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a navigation controller level in my detail view of a split view controller but when I do this I can't use my know method for testing the class type:

For example, if I don't have the navigation controller level on the detail side I can do this successfully:

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id detail = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];

    if ([detail isKindOfClass:[myDetailTVC class]]) {
        //send data to destination controller
    }   
}
```

---

If I add the navigation controller level then `self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];` will return `UINavigationController` instead of my destination controller `myDetailTVC`.

[image]

**How can I test for the destination controller for this scenario so that I can pass data to it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the UINavigationController the same way, using introspection.

Instead of checking if the object `isKindOfClass: myDetailTVC`, check if the object `isKindOfClass: UINavigationController`. Once you have found that the object `isKindOfClass: UINavigationController` access the topViewController on the `UINavigationController`'s stack, which in this case is the rootViewController or myDetailTVC.

**Example:**

```
    id object = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        // We have a navigation controller
        UINavigationController * navigationController = (UINavigationController *)object;

        // Since the only ViewController in the navigationController's stack is the 
        // rootViewController the topViewController will be myDetailTVC
        MyDetailTVC * detailViewController = (MyDetailTVC *)navigationController.topViewController;
    }
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are able to pass value to viewController but how to pass to the Navigation controller.

Lets say NavController is the navigation controller

Option 1:

```
 if ([detail isKindOfClass:[NavController class]]) {
    //send data to destination nag controller using the property visible view controller
   [detail.visibleViewController setData:data];
 }
```

Option 2:

```
if ([detail isKindOfClass:[NavController class]]) {
    //send data to destination nag controller using the property visible view controller
       for (UIViewController *controller in [contr viewControllers])
       {
          if ([controller isKindOfClass:[myDetailTVC Class])
          {
              //Do Task here
          }
       }
}
```